# Multiple date format in on column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column named **date**
In this column i've got multiple date format like this:

> 2017-06-14
>
> 04/09/15

The column type is a varchar.

I want to transform this column on datetime with this format:

> yyyy-mm-dd

I don't know how to do that when I have two different format on the same column.

Can you help about this ?

Comment: 04/09/15, is that April 9 2015, or September 4 2015, or September 15 2004, or 1904?

Comment: It's a very good idea that you want to create a new column with the appropriate data type and get rid of the old one. In your update statement you can check the string's length and then apply the appropriate conversion (`case when len(strdate) = 8 then ... else ... end`).

Comment: And if you mean multiple date format like this: `yyyy-mm-dd` & `mm/dd/yy`. Is also possible to find other formats in the same column, like `dd/mm/yy`? Or there are only 2 different formats...

Comment: The real problem here is that you aren't using the `date` data type to store a date. `varchar` is not a one size fits all data type. As for what @Jarlh said, he's spot on here. if you don't know whether `'04/09/15'` is 04 September or 09 April (or the other examples) then your data has lost all meaning and it has (effectively) become worthless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each string representation format potentially can require own conversion date style, therefore:

```
with cte as (
select '2017-06-14' DateString
union all
select '04/09/15' -- expected dateformat: dd/mm/yy
)

select 
case when DateString like '%-%-%' then CONVERT(DATE, DateString, 20) -- ODBC canonical
     when DateString like '%/%/%' then CONVERT(DATE, DateString, 3) -- French 
     else null
end
from cte
```

Results to:

```
2017-06-14
2015-09-04
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `FORMAT(CAST(@yourVarchar AS DATETIME), N'yyyy-MM-dd')` function:

```
DECLARE @f varchar(50) = '2017-06-14'
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@f AS DATETIME), N'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

OUTPUT:

```
2017-06-14
```

and your second case:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(50) = '04/09/15'
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@a AS DATETIME), N'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

OUTPUT:

```
2015-04-09
```

Answer (score 1):

For `sql-server` versions greater or equal than `2012` you can use `parse()`,

```
select parse([date] as date using 'en-US') from [your_table]
```

Or `try_parse()` which is a bit more robust,

```
select try_parse([date] as date using 'en-US') from [your_table]
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, this was super helpful. I highly recommend the try_parse method described here.

Answer (score 0):

If all of them have valid formats, simple cast will work

```
with cte as(
    select '2017-06-14' as val
    union all
    select '04/09/15' as val
)
select val, cast(val as date) from cte
```

04/09/15 will be converted as april 9th or september 4th depending on your database language